# Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

Tags: web-services, wcf, https

I have done following configuration inside configuration file for wsHttpBinding and with transport security. Meta data exchange, base address & bindings all are set for Https but it is still giving this issue.

```
<system.serviceModel>    
    <bindings>      
  <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WsHttpEndpointBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFWindowsBasicHttpBinding.Service1Behavior" name="WCFWindowsBasicHttpBinding.Service1">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsHttpEndpointBinding" name="WsHttpEndpoint" contract="WCFWindowsBasicHttpBinding.IService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>

    <endpoint address="Mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMex"></endpoint>

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://localhost/Service1.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WCFWindowsBasicHttpBinding.Service1Behavior">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: did you tried without ssl ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you hosting the service on IIS? If so, make sure the WebSite you're deploying to has an SSL Binding defined in IIS.

Comment: What does your code for creating the ServiceHost look like then?

Comment: It is a simple code which first create the hosting environment and than just open it, if in case of console or windows application deployment for https do we need to so encyrption by ourself?